# How to get build url and release url from classic release in ADO using Kusto query

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-explorer

How to get build url and release url from classic release in ADO using Kusto query

For example,

```
let orgname = "orgname";
let projectname = "team";
let daysBack = 30day;
let startDate=now() - daysBack;
Build
|project Uri,Data
| take 100
```

Here I dont find BuildUrl like

```
https://orgname.visualstudio.com/Team/_release?_a=releases&view=mine&definitionId=1742
```

List of build tables in Azure DevOps database:

- Build
- BuildArtifact
- BuildChange
- BuildDefinition
- BuildDefinitionPhaseStep
- BuildResource
- BuildTimelineRecord
- BuildWorkItem
- BuildYaml
- YamlBuildDefinitionPhaseStep

I tried looking all the build tables mentioned to get the BuildUrl but I am not able to find.

Comment: Is it related to log analytics?

Answer (score 0):

there seems is no item to get the build url and release url from the built-in tables by default.

As a workaround, you might try to use the "[**`http_request`** plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/http-request-plugin?pivots=azuredataexplorer)" to call the Azure DevOps REST API "[**Builds - Get**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)" and "[**Releases - Get Release**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get-release?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)" in the Kusto query. This plugin can send an HTTP GET request and convert the response into a table. The responses of the REST API contain the build url and release url.

---